# AppCenter Distribute in app updates for iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-app-center

I'm distributing an internal iOS app (built using Xamarin.Forms) using Visual Studio AppCenter, but can't seem to get in app updates to work.

They work fine with our Android apps, but when I download & install an app (through the email link) from a distribution group on iOS, the browser never opens to register for in app updates, and when I distribute a new release to that group, the app does not offer an update.

I've followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin and also tried creating a new distribution group, but no luck so far.

I've added the info.plist entries and started the appcenter distribute module. Analytics + Crash reporting are working OK so the AppCenter ID is fine.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Do you have the url scheme in Info.plist like explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/ios?

Comment: Hey Guillaume thanks for your reply. My apologies I pasted the wrong link into the original question (edited to fix), I've followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin and set CFBundleURLSchemes yes

Comment: Please enable verbose logging using `AppCenter.LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose` before `AppCenter.Start` and distribute that build containing logs and try to install it. Please share the logs by creating a ticket using the chat button on https://appcenter.ms (our main support center).

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumePerrot will do!